# Преобразовать из списка в словарь

Tags: python

Как из списка сделать словарь?
из

```
['a 1', 'b 2', 'c 3']
```

сделать

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Как именно сделать, чтобы ключом была буква?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
arr = ['a 1', 'b 2', 'c 3']
res = {}
for el in arr:
    key, value = el.split()
    res[key] = int(value)
```

либо так в одну строку:

```
res = {key: int(value) for key, value in map(str.split, arr)}
```

Answer (score 4):

достаточно сделать split и отдать в конструктор словаря

```
>>> dict(map(str.split, ['a 1', 'b 2', 'c 3']))
{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'}
```

---

чтобы значения были числами

```
>>> dict((k,int(v)) for k, v in map(str.split, , ['a 1', 'b 2', 'c 3']))
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Comment: Во! Самое практичное решение!

Comment: только автору надо чтобы значение было числом а не строкой

Comment: это я прозевал :( тогда не так красиво будет :)

Answer (score 3):

Решение с пояснением:

```
l = ['a 1', 'b 2', 'c 3'] # Создадим список
d = {} # "Заготовим" словарь
for i in l: # Пройдет по всем его элементам с помощью цикла for
    key, val = i.split(' ') # Pазобьем каждый элемент через пробел
    d[key] = int(val) # Добавим пару ключ значение в словарь предварительно превратив значение из строки в число
```